# Using the Grappler feat, can you grapple and pin (restrain) in the same action?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, actions, grapple

Using the Grappler feat, one can pin a grappled target. While grappling uses one of your attacks, in the rulebook pinning takes an action.

Can I, via multi-attack access to 2 attacks, use both attacks to first grapple and then pin?

Comment: Are you asking for a PC or monster? If PC, is this for a certain class?

Comment: Sorry for PC. I'm not sure why class is important, so all I can answer is it's a battlemaster goliath with grappler feat.

Comment: Wanted to ask to confirm how we should like at your multiattack question

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### This doesn't work

The attack action is only able to perform the grapple:

> ...you can use the Attack action to make a special melee attack, a grapple. If you're able to make multiple attacks with the Attack action, this attack replaces one of them.

The pin ability granted by the Grappler feat is a different action altogether:

> You can use your action to try to pin a creature grappled by you.

You would have to use your Action Surge to get an extra action (or gain it from another source) to perform both in one turn:

> On your turn, you can take one additional action.

Comment: That's what we also thought. Just wanted to make sure in case we could get away with it. Thanks.

Answer (score -4):

"When you hit a creature with an unarmed strike or an improvised weapon on your turn, you can use a bonus action to attempt to grapple the target. " - Tavern Brawler

If you were to use this feat, you would grapple as a bonus action after making an attack action and then you could use your main action to pin.
Otherwise, not possible as stated above.

Comment: If I'm reading what you wrote correctly, you have too many actions. It seems like you're saying "Attack with your action, then bonus action grapple, then use another action to pin"

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Can you clarify how you're making an Attack action, grappling as a bonus action, and then using your "main action" (which is somehow separate from the Attack action you take) to pin all in one turn?